# how to use syncfusion splitter using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, syncfusion

I need to make following functionality using angularJS without using id for controls

here is HTML code::

```
<div id="outterSpliter">
    <div id="innerSpliter">
        <div>
            <div class="cont">Pane 1 </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="cont">Pane 2 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="cont">Pane 3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is script

```
     $("#outterSpliter").ejSplitter({
    height: 250, width: 401,
    orientation: ej.Orientation.Vertical,
    properties: [{}, { paneSize: 80 }]
});

   $("#innerSpliter").ejSplitter();
```

Answer (score 1):

To render the Splitter in Angular way, use the directive '**ej-splitter**'. All JS component properties support one way biding. You need to add the prefix "e-" to the properties. Refer the below code to render the Splitter in Angular way.

```
<div ng-controller="SplitCtrl">
    <div ej-splitter e-height="250" e-width="401" e-orientation="vertical" e-properties="new">
        <div ej-splitter e-width="401">
            <div>
                <div class="cont">Pane 1 </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="cont">Pane 2 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="cont">Pane 3 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the above code snippet, for the '**e-properties**', I have specified the value "new". The "e-properties" of splitter receives array of objects as value. So in the Script section I have assigned the values of Splitter pane properties to a scope variable and assigned it as value for **e-properties**.

Script code

```
<script>
    angular.module('splitApp', ['ejangular']).controller('SplitCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.new = [{}, { paneSize: 80 }];
    });
</script> 

<style type="text/css" class="cssStyles">
    .cont {
        padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }
</style>
```